# Como puedo agregar data-attributes a las opciones usando el framework de jQuery Select2

Tags: jquery, select2

Esto es lo que tengo

```
$( "#codigo" ).select2({        
  ajax: {
    url: "getEmpleados.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term // search term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            text: item.text,
          }
        })
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Los data-attibutes se agregan en el HTML, ejemplo:

```
<select data-tags="true" data-placeholder="Select an option" data-allow-clear="true"></select>
```

Ahora, si los quieres declarar en la sentencia de JQuery, entonces quedaria así:

```
$("select").select2({
     tags: "true",
     placeholder: "Select an option",
     allowClear: true
});
```

Si lo que quieres es rellenar el Select2 usando ajax y data-attributes sería asi:

```
<select data-ajax--url="http://example.org/api/test" data-ajax--cache="true"></select>
```

Ahora, temo decirte que declarando el ajax desde los data-attributes es muy limitado.

Te dejo la documentacion de los data-atributtes aqui:

[Select2 data-atributtes](https://select2.github.io/options.html#data-attributes)

Suerte!